# Java Socket Server Not Receiving Messages?

Tags: java, sockets, protocols, listener

Alright, so I'm not sure if there really is an error or not.
I've created a listening server using Java and NetBeans, and am trying to get the protocol to work.
However, for some reason it doesn't want to accept incoming messages.
It will accept incoming connections and set up the object used for handling a client, but just wont receive any messages.

I'm not sure what's going on, am I doing something wrong? Also, I already have port 7777 port forwarded, and I'm doing testing using "127.0.0.1".

======================================================================

I currently have 3 classes:

The main class, GMServer:

```
public class GMServer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    CreateListener createListener = new CreateListener("USA Server East",7777,500);
    }
}
```

======================================================================

The CreateListener class:

```
public final class CreateListener {
private ServerSocket listenSocket = null;
private String serverName = "";
private int serverPort = 7777;
private int serverMax = 500;
private boolean terminate = false;
private double connectID = 0;
private String currentUser = "-1";
private listenParser[] connections;
private int listenArray = 0;
public listenParser[] users;
public int usercount;
private boolean listenerConnected = true;

public double getCID() {
    this.connectID++;
    return this.connectID;
    }

public CreateListener(String sName, int sPort, int sMax) throws IOException {
    //Set the server name, port, and max users.

    this.serverName = sName; this.serverPort = sPort; this.serverMax = sMax;

    //Try to create a listener socket.
    try { this.listenSocket = new ServerSocket(this.serverPort); } //If not successful, output error and end program.
    catch (IOException e) { System.err.println("Could not create a listening server on port "+this.serverPort); System.exit(7777); }

    //Let the console know that the listening server was created successfully.
    System.out.println("Creating Server: \""+serverName+"\" On Port "+serverPort+"...");

    while(listenerConnected) {
        try {
            Socket accepted = this.listenSocket.accept();
            new listenParser(accepted,getCID(),sMax).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            //Socket Wasn't Accepted?
            }
        }

    //Close down server after anything should cause the constant loop to end.
    listenSocket.close();
    }
}
```

======================================================================

and then the listenParser class (where it should be handling all traffic from clients):

```
public class listenParser extends Thread {
public Socket[] global_sockets;
public int connections = 0;
private PrintWriter _out = null;
private BufferedReader _in = null;
private double cid = 0;
private Socket socket = null;
private String currentUser = "";
private int timeout = 0;
private boolean connectionOpen = true;
private int socketTimeout = 0;
private int socketTimeoutMax = 1000;

private String room = "";
private long x = 0;
private long y = 0;

public listenParser(Socket sock, double acID, int maxUsers) {
    super("listenParser");
    this.socket = sock;
    System.out.println("Connected To A Client...");
    }

public String readString(BufferedReader tmpBuffer) {
    try {
        return tmpBuffer.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        return "";
        }
    }

public String protocol(String arg) {
    String RETURN = "";
    switch(arg) {
        case "login": currentUser = "1"; break;
        case "echo": this._out.println(readString(this._in)); break;
        default: /*Do Nothing*/ break;
        }

    //Only allow access to these commands if the user is logged in.
    if (currentUser!="") {
        switch(arg) {
            default: break;
            }
        }
    return RETURN;
    }

public boolean good() {
    if (this.currentUser.equals("")) {
        return false;
        }
    return true;
    }

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        _out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        _in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        connections++; if (connections>500) { connectionOpen = false; }

        while(connectionOpen) {
            try {
                String arguments, reply;

                arguments = this._in.readLine();

                reply = protocol(arguments);

                socketTimeout = 0;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                socketTimeout++;
                if (socketTimeout>socketTimeoutMax) {
                    connectionOpen = false; break;
                    }
                }
            }

        _out.close();
        _in.close();
        socket.close();

        System.out.println("Client Disconnected...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: guess, you need to provide a client code and sample logs from server and client

Comment: I would suggest instrumenting your code with some `print` statements to see what's going on, or use the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

You are reading lines. Are you *sending* lines? Very common mistake. `readLine()` will block until it receives a newline, or EOS.

Speaking of EOS, the first thing you must do with the result of `readLine()` is check it for null, and if so close the socket and break out of the reading loop.